# query IIS application pool configuration fails in IIS7 when code running in worker

Tags: windows, winapi, iis-7

When querying iis7 config data it fails when running within the worker process and ok in console application.

```
        COSERVERINFO     csiMachineName;

        csiMachineName.pAuthInfo     = NULL;
        csiMachineName.dwReserved1 = 0;
        csiMachineName.dwReserved2 = 0;
        csiMachineName.pwszName      = L"localhost";

        hr = CoGetClassObject(
            __uuidof( AppHostAdminManager ),
            CLSCTX_SERVER,
            &csiMachineName,
            IID_IClassFactory,
            (void**) &(pClassFactory.GetInterfacePtr()));

        hr = pClassFactory->CreateInstance(
            NULL, __uuidof( IAppHostAdminManager ), (void **) &(iisAdmin.GetInterfacePtr()));

        bstr_t bstrSectionName("system.applicationHost/applicationPools");
        bstr_t bstrPath("MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST");

        hr = iisAdmin->GetAdminSection(bstrSectionName, bstrPath, &(sitesElement.GetInterfacePtr()) );

        hr = sitesElement->get_Collection(&(sitesElementCollection.GetInterfacePtr()));

    DWORD sitesCount = 0;
        hr = sitesElementCollection->get_Count(&sitesCount);
```

and `sitesCount` is 0 when this code run in IIS module but ok when running in windows application.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is that the Application Pool identity doesn't have proper rights to administrate IIS.  Try setting the application pool identity to the same as the user you use when running the console app and see if that makes a difference.  If it does, you may need to set this code in a separate AppPool running as an elevated user to let the code run while limiting what code runs as the elevated user.

Comment: thanks. tried to set the user in the admin group but that didn't help.